# Append an incremental counter to duplicate values in list

Tags: list, python-2.7

In Python I'm trying to take:

```
mylist=[a,a,a,b,b,c]
```

and make it into:

```
mylist=[(a,0),(a,1),(a,2),(b,0),(b,1),(c,0)]
```

Comment: In your example, all equal values are contiguous.  Is that always true?

Comment: So, what is your question?  What have you tried? What problems have your run into? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, you can't just post your homework assignment or task requirements and demand somebody produce the code. But if you've worked on a problem yourself and run into a specific problem, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for your feedback. My apologies, I was trying to be as direct as possible without adding confusion from my very messy and amateurish failed attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
l = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
out = []
for e in l:
    out.append((e, c[e]))
    c[e] += 1
print(out)
```

Here is another one, which assumed that input list is sorted:

```
from itertools import groupby
print(tuple((e, idx) for _, group in groupby(l) for idx, e in enumerate(group)))
```